# I want to get a new start time from an external source and reload WaveSurferPlayer

Tags: reactjs

Title: WaveSurferPlayer component not playing when changeStartTime is updated

Description:
Hello, I am currently working on a React project where I have a SoundDetail component that receives a `changeStartTime` prop. The `SoundDetail` component includes a `WaveSurferPlayer` component, and I want the `WaveSurferPlayer` to play again when the `changeStartTime` prop is updated.

I have tried using `useEffect` in the `WaveSurferPlayer` component to listen for changes in `changeStartTime` and play the audio accordingly. However, it's not working as expected, and the `WaveSurferPlayer` doesn't play when `changeStartTime` changes.

```
// SoundDetail.jsx
const SoundDetail = ({ item, changeStartTime }) => {
  // ... other code

  return (
    <WaveSurferPlayer
      height={100}
      barWidth={3}
      barHeight={1}
      barGap={2}
      waveColor="#c75000"
      progressColor="#1c1c1c"
      url={url}
      changeStartTime={changeStartTime}
    />
  );
};

// WaveSurferPlayer.jsx
export const WaveSurferPlayer = (props) => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const [playState, setPlayState] = useState(false);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const wavesurfer = useWavesurfer(containerRef, props);
  // ... other code

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!wavesurfer) return;

    setPlayState(false);
    console.log(wavesurfer.getDuration());
  
    // changeStartTime is not updating the playback
    wavesurfer.seekTo(props.changeStartTime / wavesurfer.getDuration());
    wavesurfer.play();

    const subscriptions = [
      wavesurfer.on("play", () => setPlayState(true)),
      wavesurfer.on("pause", () => setPlayState(false)),
      wavesurfer.on("timeupdate", (currentTime) => setCurrentTime(currentTime)),
    ];

    return () => {
      subscriptions.forEach((unsub) => unsub());
    };
  }, [wavesurfer]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={containerRef} style={{ minHeight: "120px" }} />
      {/* ... other code */}
    </>
  );
};

=
Hello, I am currently working on a React project where I have a SoundDetail component that receives a `changeStartTime` prop. The `SoundDetail` component includes a `WaveSurferPlayer` component, and I want the `WaveSurferPlayer` to play again when the `changeStartTime` prop is updated.

I have tried using `useEffect` in the `WaveSurferPlayer` component to listen for changes in `changeStartTime` and play the audio accordingly. However, it's not working as expected, and the `WaveSurferPlayer` doesn't play when `changeStartTime` changes.
```